# How to retrieve custom property in isolate scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've read quite a lot examples on how to do binding in an isolate scope but not how to retrieve scope custom properties in template.

I think the fix must be very simple but I just don't figure out what's wrong here

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div my-directive>

  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            data.myProperty:"1234"
        },
        template:'Inside myDirective, isolate scope: {{ data.myProperty }}'
      };
    })
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Somehow, data.myProperty couldn't be reached.

Comment: AngularJS 1.2.0-rc.3? The year is 2018, not 2013. AngularJS 1.7 is the final release and the framework goes into end-of-life support on 1July2018. See [Stable AngularJS and Long Term Support](https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly use and access bounded properties in bindings like you were doing `data.myProperty:"1234"`. It will eventually result in error.

You have to pass custom property via `attribute` of your directive. Over here you can consider adding `custom-data` attribute, add mention the scope property name over it. So it would be passed to isolated scope directive.

**Controller**

```
$scope.data = {
   myProperty: 'My Property Value'
}
```

**Html**

```
<div my-directive custom-data="data">

</div>
```

**directive**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        customData: '=data'
        //without alias it will look like below.
        //customData: '='
    },
    template:'Inside myDirective, isolate scope: {{ data.myProperty }}'
    //without alias template would look like below
    //template:'Inside myDirective, isolate scope: {{ customData.myProperty }}'
  };
})
```

> **Note:** It seems like you are using older unstable version. If possible update angular to latest angularjs 1.7.x version, to find more features and performant angularjs. After `1.5.x` version, you could also use `<` inside binding (`customData: '<data'`) to keep one way data binding flow. Just to not confuse you I used `=`(two way data binding) for demo.

Comment: Does it mean all property values need to bind to attributes. We can't do regular key-value pair setup in isolate scope like the one I tried in the question?

Comment: No that isn't possible, either pass object or specific value.

Comment: One-way `<` binding was introduced in V1.5. The OP is using 1.2.0-rc.3.

Comment: @georgeawg thanks for heads up, I missed the angularjs verison that OP were using..